# Dynamically generate an accordion based on array data

Tags: php, arrays, dynamic, bootstrap-4, accordion

I am reading mysql fine to pull a set of data given a particular ID, this returns an array to my script.  Thats the easy bit.  Example of which is here an is stored in an array called $history

```
Array ( [serviceID] => 1 [VesselTag] => 1000001 [component] => Engine 1 [item] => Caterpillar [serial] => 123456 [comment] => Something in here like this [parts] => Oil [lat] => 50.38313740 [longitude] => -4.03461360 [engineer] => 27 [date] => 2019-05-30 19:25:56 ) 
Array ( [serviceID] => 2 [VesselTag] => 1000001 [component] => Engine 2 [item] => Caterpillar [serial] => 677889 [comment] => Did a full overhaul of top section replaced everything [parts] => everything [lat] => 50.38309180 [longitude] => -4.03468820 [engineer] => 27 [date] => 2019-05-30 19:27:29 ) 
Array ( [serviceID] => 3 [VesselTag] => 1000001 [component] => Engine 1 [item] => Caterpillar [serial] => 123456 [comment] => This seems quite usable [parts] => Oil [lat] => 50.38345892 [longitude] => -4.03475649 [engineer] => 27 [date] => 2019-05-30 19:29:23 )
```

What I would like to do is now generate an accordion 'card-body' grouping the cards based on [component]s from the list.  Sometime the array may have more or less, so there is going to be anywhere from 0 to 7 cards [components] showing.

````
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-header">
    <a class="card-link" data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseOne">
        $array[Component]  **<--- Guessing this would be from a ```foreach``` or ```while``` loop???**
    </a>
  </div>
  <div id="collapseOne" class="collapse" data-parent="#accordion">
    <div class="card-body">
      <?php **THIS IS WHERE I WILL DISPLAY THE ROWS OF DATA ASSOCIATED TO THE [component] IN QUESTION ?>**
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
````

I am just really struggling getting my head around which loop to use, and to be able to drive it by the [components].

Its doing my head in......

Comment: I should probably add I am trying to do this without making lots of calls to the DB...  Idea is to pull all the history for a particular 'VesselID' and then generate the accordion dependent on the components that are in those records.  Each accordion will then list those records for the specific accordion [component]

Comment: try this one should work just wrap the card in accordion div
<?php foreach ($history as $data): ?>
  <div class="card-body">
  <?php echo $data['serviceID'] ?>
  <?php echo $data['VesselTag'] ?>
  <?php echo $data['component'] ?>
    </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After quite some time looking at different articles I seem to have come up with something that works.....
I think it is relatively efficient, but happy for someone to tell me otherwise....

```
<div id="accordion">
    <?php $newArray=array();
            foreach($history as $val){
                $key=$val['component'];
                $grouped[$key][]=$val;
            }
            foreach($grouped as $group){?>
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">
                        <a class="card-link" data-toggle="collapse" href="#<?php echo str_replace(' ', '',$group[0]['component']); ?>">
                            <?php echo $group[0]['component']; ?>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div id="<?php echo str_replace(' ', '',$group[0]['component']); ?>" class="collapse" data-parent="#accordion">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <?php foreach ($group as $occurance){
                                echo $occurance['date'] . ' - ' . $occurance['comment'] . ' - ' . $occurance['parts'] . ' - ' . $occurance['engineer'];
                                echo '<br>';
                                } ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
        <?php }?>
</div>
```