# php - Accordion Content Using PHP/MySQL Query Data

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, dynamic, accordion

I have a list of soccer results stored in a MySQL database. Where a result meets a specific criteria, I've been able to use a PHP/SQL query to generate a static list where each result is grouped by its appropriate season using the solution provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21967293/5264403).

The structure of the table from which I'm looping the data through (plus example data) is this:

```
Date          Season          Comp          Opponent          Score          Match ID
======================================================================================
1980-08-16    1980-1          UCL1          2                 3-2            1
1980-09-23    1980-1          UCL1          4                 1-0            5
1981-01-13    1980-1          UCL1          11                0-2            20
1982-03-24    1981-2          UCLP          9                 2-2            42
1982-09-15    1982-3          UCLP          24                0-0            58
1982-12-12    1982-3          UCLP          20                4-1            74
1983-02-04    1982-3          UCLP          26                0-2            90
1983-05-01    1982-3          UCLP          25                1-1            104
```

Using the above linked solution, I can bring through the data to create a basic static list like this:

```
1980-1
- Result 1: 1980-08-16, 3-2 (vs. 2)
- Result 2: 1980-09-23, 1-0 (vs. 4)
- Result 3: 1981-01-13, 0-2 (vs. 11)
1981-2
- Result 4: 1982-03-24, 2-2 (vs .9) 
1982-3
- Result 5: 1982-09-15, 0-0 (vs. 24)
- Result 6: 1982-12-12, 4-1 (vs. 20)
... and so on
```

But instead of showing results in a static list, the goal is to use this data to dynamically generate a jQuery accordion – using individual seasons as **panel buttons/headers** and then filtering relevant results into the **panel-body**. The query/code I've so far developed to try and achieve this is:

```
$query = "SELECT mt.ID,mt.ID1,re.date,re.season,re.venue,re.comp,re.opponent,re.score,ce.name,ce.ID,re.ID FROM resultengine re INNER JOIN matchteam mt ON re.ID=mt.ID INNER JOIN clubengine ce ON re.opponent=ce.ID WHERE (mt.ID1='0' or mt.ID1='9998') ORDER BY re.season ASC, re.date ASC";
$result2 = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query) or trigger_error("Query Failed! SQL: $query - Error: ". mysqli_error($mysqli), E_USER_ERROR);
$totalRows = mysqli_num_rows($result2);

if($result2) {
    if ($totalRows == 0) {
        echo "<p>No games here</p>";
    }
    else {
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)) {
        {$yearonly = date("l d F Y",strtotime($row['2']));}
        if($row['3'] != $season) {
            echo "<button class='accordion'>";
            echo $row['3'];
            $season = $row['3'];
            echo "</button>";
        }
        echo "<div class='panel'>";
        echo "<h4 class='result-date'>".$yearonly."</h4>";
        echo "<div class='result-info'>";
            echo "<a href='/seasons/match/".$row['10']."/' class='result-data result-link'>";
            echo "<span class='result-column sidebar-comp'>".$row['5']."</span>";   
            echo "<span class='result-column sidebar-venue'>".$row['4']."</span>";
            echo "<span class='result-column sidebar-team'>".$row['8']."</span>";
            echo "<span class='result-column sidebar-score'>";
                echo "<span class='player-score-box'>";
                    echo "<span class='player-score-main'>".$row['7']."</span>";
                echo "</span>";
            echo "</span>"; 
            echo "</a>";
            echo "</div>";
        echo "</div>";
        }
    }
}
```

I know that this current code will create a new `<div class='panel'>` for each individual result. So, this means one result is visible under each season – the live example is [here](https://www.boroguide.co.uk/missing). To get it showing as intended with **all** results from one season showing in the appropriate panel, I'm missing a step (or component) from my query – and I can't work out what it is.

My initial thought is that I need to use `foreach` in some capacity, but can't figure this out. I've used answers to questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56395502/dynamically-generate-an-accordion-based-on-array-data) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21967276/group-mysql-results-by-category-and-display-them-into-groups-under-each-category) as possible solutions. But I've either ended up having season panels repeated based on how many results correspond or the first result from each season being repeated multiple times. What am I missing to get the desired outcome?

I could probably make it work with a nested query, but am led to believe this should be avoided?

Comment: show table structure, and sample data, thanks.

Comment: Have updated to include this, thanks.